# File not available on remote system after creating it. Windows network latency?

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008

I have an asp.net web application. When it needs to produce a file on a remote system, it makes a call (over tcp/ip) to a process on the same machine that creates the file. It creates it on a network share. When that process is finished writing out the file, it sends an "OK" response back to my asp.net application.  I'm sure you see where this is headed. When the asp.net application checks if the file exists (using File.Exists()), it can sometimes take as long as 8 seconds for it to be "found". Could there be some kind of directory info being cached across windows networking? And would it be per processs?

In summary, one process creates the file, and it takes up to 8 seconds before the other process can see it. How can I overcome this? Again, this is standard windows netorking. Server 2008 to server 2008.

Have some updates from experimenting: Another program running on the desktop can see the file a lot sooner than the asp.net application can. The difference can be 7-10 seconds. Why would the ASP.NET iis service take so long to see the remote file?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Is the share perhaps a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29) share? If the answer is yes, then it *is* there, but only on one machine, and the second time you connect to that share you may be connecting to another machine that does not have the file yet, as it is still replicating.

Comment: well i'm out of ideas then. maybe try asking on server fault